# save data to chrome.storage.sync on closing of popup - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've tried many ways but no event listener is getting triggered on/before closing of popup.
You may find related questions on SO but nothing worked for me.
Here's what I tried:

```
 chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function hello() {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({
            'somedata': 'mydata1' // didn't work
        }, function() {});
    });

addEventListener("unload", function(event) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        'somedata': 'mydata2'  // didn't work
    }, function() {});
}, true);
```

I just want to save some data when user closes the popup. That's all.

Comment: Simply save the data on every `change` and `input` event to a temporary key in chrome.storage.sync, thus you won't lose data if the browser/computer suddenly crashes. This is how user-friendly apps work, they always save current state immediately.

Comment: Moreover, extension popup unload event support was always [unreliable and shaky](https://crbug.com/31262). Also, in your case the `sync.set` callback is asynchronous and it is destroyed with the popup window *before* it is invoked.

Comment: You should either do as @wOxxOm stated (i.e. save upon every change), or have "Save" and "Cancel" buttons. From a UI perspective, the user will expect every change they make to have lasting effect unless there is an explicit way for them to commit the changes & a clear way for them to exit the popup/panel without committing changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's bugged so you have to do workarounds.

You'll have to save the data from the background page, so you need to pass the data to it from your popup.

Use `chrome.runtime.connect` to connect the two. A port is established: whenever the data you want to save from your popup changes you can `Port.postMessage()` to your background page.

When the popup closes, `Port.onDisconnect` will fire, and your data will be ready to sync.